# Displaying Shortcut indicators on Menu headers when pressing Alt key

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I display the shortcut for each menu header when the user presses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Here is the effect in Microsoft Word 2010, which I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

Comment: only text like "Ctrl+N" i've done that underline thing.i want the same effect when you press 'Alt' in Microsoft Word 2010.have u seen that,just check it out!

Comment: Yes Grant perfect!!! can u suggest me something for it.

Comment: What about using the WPF Ribbon control? (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.100%29.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

To enable this capability, you must set the property "KeyTips" in ribbontabitem or any control of ribbon family.